# Javascript execution order when pulling Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After I authenticate to Firebase with Google auth, I get this `console.log` output and the JavaScript seems to bounce around in execution order. Here's my console output and the javascript code.

Why does "controller is: Pellet_Pirate_1" display at the log end rather than at the beginning where the code executes to pull this value from Firebase?  My "GLOBAL CONTROLLER" and other logs of the `contr` global variable should be valued as well... I am trying to use `contr` as a global variable and it is defined at the top of my script tag

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I've banged my head on this one for many hours now!

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCPGL.jpg)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var contr = undefined;
function PelletPirate() { 
    this.userPic = document.getElementById('user-pic');
    this.userName = document.getElementById('user-name');
    this.signInButton = document.getElementById('sign-in');
    this.signOutButton = document.getElementById('sign-out');
    this.signOutButton.addEventListener('click', this.toggleSignOut.bind(this));
    this.signInButton.addEventListener('click', this.toggleSignIn.bind(this));
    this.initFirebase();
}

// Sets up shortcuts to Firebase features and initiate firebase auth.
PelletPirate.prototype.initFirebase = function() {
    //FlymanEdit Shortcuts to Firebase SDK features.
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
    this.database = firebase.database();
    this.storage = firebase.storage();
    //FlymanEdit Initiates Firebase auth and listen to auth state changes.
    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged.bind(this));
};

PelletPirate.prototype.toggleSignIn = function() {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); // [Start createprovider]
        provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'); // [START addscopes]
        this.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) 
        { 
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;
            console.log('token: ' + token);

        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            var email = error.email;
            var credential = error.credential; // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            if (errorCode === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
                alert('You have already signed up with a different auth provider for that email.');
            } 
            else {   
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
}

// Sign-out.
PelletPirate.prototype.toggleSignOut = function() {
    this.auth.signOut();
    console.log('********************  USER SIGNED OUT  *********************');
};

PelletPirate.prototype.onAuthStateChanged = function(user) {  // Triggers when user's auth state changes.
    if (user) { // User is signed in!
        // let's go fetch the Pellet Pirate controller name based on the logged in user!
        console.log('user.uid is: ' + user.uid);
        firebase.database().ref().child("owners").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(user.uid).on('value', function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            contr = childSnapshot.val().controller;
            //MYLIBRARY.init([controller, 1, "controller"]);
            //MYLIBRARY.passVar();
            console.log('controller is: ' + contr);
            return contr;           
            });
        });             
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var profilePicUrl = user.photoURL;
        var userName = user.displayName;
        var displayName = user.displayName;
        var email = user.email;
        var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
        var photoURL = user.photoURL;
        var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
        var uid = user.uid;
        var refreshToken = user.refreshToken;
        var providerData = user.providerData;
        //console.log('You have signed in: ' + userName );
        console.log('*************** signed in: ' + userName + ' *****************');
        console.log('GLOBAL CONTROLLER: ' + contr);

        document.getElementById('authed').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('authed2').style.visibility = 'visible';   
        document.getElementById('gauges').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('graph').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('parameters').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('ParmForm').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('ClearDataButton').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('AddProgramButton').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
        document.getElementById('programrows').style.visibility = 'visible'; 

        // Set the user's profile pic and name.
        this.userPic.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + profilePicUrl + ')';
        this.userName.textContent = userName;

        // Show user's profile and sign-out button.
        this.userName.removeAttribute('hidden');
        this.userPic.removeAttribute('hidden');
        this.signOutButton.removeAttribute('hidden');

        // Hide sign-in button.
        this.signInButton.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');   



        console.log('before firebase controller is: ' + contr);
        //controllerName = "Pellet_Pirate_1";

        //Firebase  
        var TempsRef = Ref.child('ControllerData/' + contr + '/Temps');

        console.log('after firebase controller is: ' + contr);

        TempsRef.limitToLast(3600/3*16).once("value", function(snapshot) { //Limit to last 16 hours
            var Ts = snapshot.val();
            for (var k in Ts) {
                T1.push([Ts[k].time, Ts[k].T1]);
                T2.push([Ts[k].time, Ts[k].T2]);
                T3.push([Ts[k].time, Ts[k].T3]);
                TT.push([Ts[k].time, Ts[k].TT]);
                console.log('in snapshot');
            }
            TempsRef.limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) { //Establish callback
                var Ts = snapshot.val();
                T1.push([Ts.time, Ts.T1]);
                T2.push([Ts.time, Ts.T2]);
                T3.push([Ts.time, Ts.T3]);
                TT.push([Ts.time, Ts.TT]);
                UpdatePlot();
                console.log('in snapshot-previousChildKey' );
                //console.log('in snapshot-PCK-controllerName is:' + controllerName);
            });
            UpdatePlot();
        });

        TempsRef.on("child_removed", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
            T1 = [];
            T2 = [];
            T3 = [];
            TT = [] ; 
            UpdatePlot();
        });
    } 

    else { // User is signed out!
        // Hide user's profile and sign-out button.
        this.userName.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
        this.userPic.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
        this.signOutButton.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');

        document.getElementById('authed').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('authed2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('gauges').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('graph').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('parameters').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('ParmForm').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('ClearDataButton').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('AddProgramButton').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('programrows').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        // Show sign-in button.
        this.signInButton.removeAttribute('hidden');

        // undefine the controller
        contr = undefined;
    }
}; // [ END onAuthStateChanged - auth state listener]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `on()` is asynchronous.  It returns immediately while the query is happening in the background. Meanwhile, the code immediately after that runs until the first time the callback you provided to it is invokes with a snapshot of results.

Comment: thank you Doug. Is there a way to make it synchronous?  I'm getting exactly what you demo'd in your medium.com article!  Would the new JavaScript async/await method work here from your medium.com article?

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is async.  That's a core part of the language.  You can't change that, nor should you want to.  You can't use async/await for on(), because it doesn't return a promise, and th e listener doesn't finish until you call off().  Maybe you want to use once() instead, if you just want a single value a single time.

Comment: I tried replacing on() with once() but to no avail.  it operates the same way. Basically i need this callback to return the users controller name because I need it when the user logs in so I can tell firebase where to write the users data. it's part of my multi-tenant model. Is there a different approach i should try here or any reference post you could point me to that might have an approach that could work?  again, thanks for the help!

Comment: As I said, everything in JavaScript is async (as are all Firebase APIs).  You would switch from on() to once() if you need data a single time, and then you can use the promise it returns to continue execution.  Use of promises is pretty foundational to JavaScript - learn them.

Comment: thanks Doug. I've reviewed your youtube videos on promises and I'm trying to learn it. I'm an intermediate c++ embedded programmer, learning javascript! Can you point me to a good tutorial or example that executes the promise to get what I'm after? thanks for any help.